# Merging two sorted lists when recursion isn't an option - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, list, sorting, linked-list

I am completely stumped. I have looked up examples upon examples upon solutions and nothing is structured like this.

The objective is to combine two linked lists in a sorted fashion from smallest number to larger.

The problem is it must be done so using a method that is called by an object of the created list class that accepts the list of another object of the list class.

EDIT: I am assuming it is not possible to use recursion due to the form of the signature of the method. Correct me if that is not the case.

ie.

```
 list2.mergeSort(list1.getList()); // getList() is a method that returns the list of 
                                   // that object
```

the signature would look like

```
 public List<Integer> mergeSort(List<Integer> otherList)
```

After combining list 1 and the other list 2 you would store your resulting merged list in list 1 and have it returned by the mergeSort() method.

I should add that the list could be an array or integers, an ArrayList, or some other list or array form if another form is better than the List form I have chosen.

Possible Solution?

```
 public List<Integer> mergeSort(List<Integer> otherList){

    List<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for(int x = 0; x<list.size(); x++){
        if(list.get(x) < otherList.get(x))
            temp.add(list.get(x));
        else
            temp.add(otherList.get(x));
    }

    list = temp;

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Iterate over both lists simultaneously; put the smaller of the two current values into the merged list next, advance only that iterator. Continue until both lists were iterated completely.

Comment: May your sorted list (before and after the merge) have duplicate elements ?

Comment: Yes. The point is if you have list 1 = [0, 12, 34, 2] and list 2 = [2, 32, 4, 66] after calling the mergeSort method your list 2 should now look like list 2 = [0, 2, 2, 4, 12, 32, 34. 66]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy (*recommended for a real project*) way:

```
public MyList<E> mergeSort(Collection<? extends E> list) {
    this.addAll(list);
    Collections.sort(this);
    return this;
}
```

A more detailed way:

```
public MyList<E> mergeSort(Collection<? extends E> list1) {
    //Copy this list in another one and clear it
    List<E> list2 = new ArrayList<E>(this);
    this.clear();
    //Merge values until one list is exhausted
    Iterator<? extends E> it1 = list1.iterator();
    Iterator<? extends E> it2 = list2.iterator();
    if (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
        E value1 = it1.next(), value2 = it2.next();
        do {
            if (value1.compareTo(value2) <= 0) {
                this.add(value1);
                if (it1.hasNext()) {
                    value1 = it1.next();
                } else {
                    this.add(value2);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                this.add(value2);
                if (it2.hasNext()) {
                    value2 = it2.next();
                } else {
                    this.add(value1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    //copy remaining values
    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        this.add(it1.next());
    }
    while (it2.hasNext()) {
        this.add(it2.next());
    }
    return this;
}
```

My class definition looks like this:

```
public class MyList<E extends Comparable<E>>
    extends ArrayList<E> {
```

Comment: Your first "real project" way was the one I tried but it was adding the second list twice. I think I got the naming wrong. I will give it a try again.

Comment: Yup it's definitely adding the second list being passed twice.

Comment: Not in my tests, can I have a look at how you create the list and call the mergeSort method ? Maybe you should better use the [utility functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25298018/2191722) from @Baldy 's solution

Comment: the lists are created randomly with the items added to each list as nodes using generics. If I print out the list each has the correct number of elements but something is going wrong after it is passed. 

I have added the values to lists like so:

    public List<Integer> getList(){

  Node<Integer> cursor = head;
  
  while(cursor.getNext() != null){
   list.add(cursor.getData());
   cursor=cursor.getNext();
   }
  
  return list;
 }



Sorry you'll have to copy to see is clearly. This gives me the list for that object.

Comment: I call the mergeSort method as I typed it above.  list2.mergeSort(list1.getList());

Comment: So the issue was in how I called the mergeSort method.

My new issue is how to iterate through the list. The enhanced for loop I am using does not seem to be working.

Comment: By the way, this ```while(cursor.getNext() != null){ list.add(cursor.getData()); cursor=cursor.getNext(); }``` is weird, it looks like you'll either have a NullPointerException if ```head``` is null or like you're missing the last element of the list. Unless you have an empty trailing Node in your implementation.

Comment: You are correct. I was missing the last element so I got it to make one extra so the correct amount would be added. You have helped me greatly the second half of my problem was fix my declaring the List<Integer> list as a new ArrayList instead of a LinkedList. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want the merging to be done *in-place*?  If so, it's not really all that different from the ordinary merge-two-lists problem.

Since I'm not familiar with Java, I'll write the pseudocode version of the algorithm (assuming both `list1` and `list2` are already sorted):

```
let Y refer to the first element in list2
for X in list1 (traversed in ascending order):
    while Y < X:
        insert Y before X
        change Y to point to the next element
while Y is still a valid reference:
    append Y to list1
    change Y to point to the next element
```

The algorithm here *destructively* modifies `list1` and inserts each element of `list2` into the correct place.  Change `<` to `<=` if you want `list2` to be preferred when equal elements are compared.

Comment: Would it be like the possible solution I provided above (doesn't work so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong)?

Comment: Your solution fails to iterate over *both* lists: your index `i` is only drawn from the indices of `list` (I don't even know what `list` is since it appears to be an undeclared variable).

Comment: Sorry it was a piece of the whole class so it declared above. Either I have found a working solution. It is messy but it works.

Answer (score 0):

`List` iterators maintain **insertion order** so they're not really designed to do what you want although you could sort your list after merging them using `Collections.sort()`.

```
public List<T> mergeSort(List<T> one, List<T> two) {
    List<T> rc = new ArrayList<>(one.size() + two.size());
    rc.addAll(one);
    rc.addAll(two);
    Collections.sort(rc);
    return rc;
}
```

You could add a `Comparator` here to get control over the sort.

You're better off using a `Set` collection as they will be automatically sorted based on the type. If you're OK with that, here'e the method:

```
public Set<T> mergeSort(Set<T> one, Set<T> two) {
    Set<T> rc = new TreeSet<>(one);
    rc.addAll(two);
    return rc;
}
```

Again, you can add a `Comparator` here, too.

Not exactly what you wanted but rather than extending `ArrayList` or `TreeSet` you get a generic method you can use anywhere. For your question, I'd use it like this:

```
list1 = Utility.mergeSort(list1, list2);
```

Comment: The problem with your solution and the reason why I am running into problems is your signature for the mergeSort(). the mergeSort method is only passed the second list to be added to the first list of the object calling the method. Both list are not simultanously passed to this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct an `Iterable` that can merge two other `Iterable`s so long as they are `Comparable`.

```
class MergedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
    // The two Iterables we are merging.
    private final Iterable<T> a;
    private final Iterable<T> b;

    // Varargs version left to the student.
    public MergedList(Iterable<T> a, Iterable<T> b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            // Grab iterators.
            private final Iterator<T> ia = a.iterator();
            private final Iterator<T> ib = b.iterator();
            // Prime both pumps.
            private T na = ia.hasNext() ? ia.next() : null;
            private T nb = ib.hasNext() ? ib.next() : null;
            // Next to deliver.
            private T n = null;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (n == null) {
                    // Pick one - either null means the other one - otherwise compare.
                    n = na == null ? nb : nb == null ? na : na.compareTo(nb) < 0 ? na : nb;
                    if (n != null) {
                        // Consume one.
                        if (na != null && n == na) {
                            // Get next from a.
                            na = ia.hasNext() ? ia.next() : null;
                        } else if (nb != null && n == nb) {
                            // Get next from b.
                            nb = ib.hasNext() ? ib.next() : null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return n != null;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                T next = n;
                n = null;
                return next;
            }

        };
    }
}

public void test() {
    List<String> a = Arrays.asList("A", "C", "E");
    List<String> b = Arrays.asList("B", "D", "F");
    for (String s : new MergedList<>(a, b)) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not to add more methods then I have said or change the basic structure of the mergeSort signature.

Comment: @EMMERZOH - Then you are doomed to building a new list which may bite you if the list gets big. My solution takes no more memory and merges the two lists on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public List<Integer> mergeSort(List<Integer> otherList){
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); // this should be list1
        list1.addAll(otherList);

        /** can also use Collections.sort(list1); */
        Collections.sort(list1,new Comparator<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2); //Change to o2.CompareTo(o1) for descending order
            }
        });
        return list1;
    }
```